# Include mixin from gem, not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a problem when trying to include mixin from gem file to be used via console.

```
require "fertilizer/version"

module Fertilizer
  # <-- CONSOLE EXTENSION (CONSOLE ONLY)-->
  # Following part of code is active with the start of IRB console. 
  # Details about features can be seen in console_extensions module.

  if defined?(Rails::Console)
    require 'fertilizer/console_extensions'
    include ConsoleExtensions
  end

  # <-- OBJECT EXTENSIONS (CONSOLE ONLY)-->
  if defined?(Rails::Console)
    require 'fertilizer/object_extensions'
  end
end
```

Gem has ruby file **fertilizer.rb** which executes code above, when I start console I can see code being triggered. But when I try to use methods from mixin, console can't find them.

If I take exact same code and put it in *initializer* mixin gets loaded (as before) but this time I am able to use methods from  mixin in consle.

How can I fix my gem file so that when gem loads, mixin methods are available via console?

Comment: It sound like you fixed it already if using an initializer works.

Comment: Well I would like to create gem that will do that for you. If I need to create initializer than I need to generate that initializer. Too much hassle just to add few methods to be available via console.

Comment: I figured out so far that I am probably missing "self", that is "self" from initializer probably targets rails apps and "self" from gem initializing is something else. Working on it.

Comment: Ok figured out the problem but not sure how to solve it, gem file fertilizer.rb is required but not included. I need to send(:include, self) but not sure via which class to trigger it.

Comment: Who is the receiver of `include ConsoleExtensions`? What is the value of `self`?

Comment: `self` refers to the current execution context. If you ever need to know for sure, either `puts self.inspect` or `puts self.class`

Comment: I have added some more code to better explain. 'self' is in this case is module itself so when I include it I include it in module. But I need somehow to tell 'console' to 'include Fertilizer' and I am not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

More discussion can be found here:

[How to automatically include Gem in the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011030/how-to-automatically-include-gem-in-the-path/)

Solution is:

```
Object.send(:include, self)
```

Not happy with solution but it works.