# How to automatically include Gem in the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have foo.gem and there is `lib/foo.rb` in there.

When I add gem to Gemfile it's foo.rb is automatically required in my path. But I need to include it automatically. Reason for this is I am making console extension and I want them to be available without me writing `include Foo'.

I am experimenting with

```
SOME_CLASS.send(:include, Foo)
```

But not sure what class to use to have it added to the path e.g. when I start console that is automatically included. Here are some mixins automatically included in console, I need mine to be there :) Thank you

```
irb(main):006:0> self.class.included_modules
=> [PP::ObjectMixin, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, Kernel]
```

P.S.

I can solve problem with initializer but I don't want to change project's code I just want to add gem and that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`Kernel`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html) module, which is included by  [`Object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html).  It's where private methods like `exit`, `puts` and `require` are defined, so it is an excellent choice for defining an imperative API.

When you extend `Object`, people expect to be able to call your methods explicitly on any object, and they also understand that your method depends on that object's state.

`Kernel` methods understood differently. Even though they're technically available to all objects, you don't expect people to write things like:

```
'some string'.sleep 1000
```

This makes no sense. [`sleep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) has nothing to do with the string; it doesn't depend on it in any way. It should only be called with an implicit receiver, as if the very concept of `self` didn't exist.

Making your methods private and extending `Kernel` instead helps you get that message across.

---

You can do that in `foo.rb`:

```
module Foo
  # …
end

Some::Class.send :include, Foo
```

When you `load` or `require` some file, it is executed line by line. You can put arbitrary code anywhere in the file, even inside module and class definitions. You can take advantage of that in order to properly set up your library so that others don't have to.

Comment: I want it to be available in console, "some class" was a question on what to use. As it turns out it works with 'Object.send(:include, Foo)'.

Comment: @Dolphin, sorry, I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer with a few reasons why you should use `Kernel` instead.

Comment: You are right makes more sense to use it in 'Kernel'. There seems to be bug or some inner-working that I don't understand which require me to do 'Kernel.send(:include,self)' and after re-include 'Kernel' to 'Object' since it was not working without it, 'Object.send(:include,Kernel)'. 

Bottom of line method ended up in 'Object' and even if it is more lines of code it is better way to do it by encapsulating to 'Kernel'. Can you suggest any material I could use to educate myself better in these core Ruby workings?

Comment: @Dolphin, you do have to use `send` because `include` is a private method. Alternatively, you could open the `Kernel` module as if you were defining it for the first time. However, you _shouldn't_ have to include `Kernel` in `Object` a second time. What exactly are you doing? As for material, there's plenty on the Internet; search for `ruby module mixin`. [Here](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/mixin.htm)'s one.

Comment: You can see it [here](https://github.com/hkraji/fertilizer/blob/master/lib/fertilizer.rb) basically its a gem which will when added to rails project automaticly add new methods when using console. (e.g. method reload_lib will reload lib folder allowing you to change code without having to restart console).

Comment: @Dolphin, that's strange. Try `Kernel.send :include, ConsoleExtensions` instead of including it in the main `Fertilizer` module. You can also ask a question here; someone will probably be able to figure it out. ;)

Comment: Same as before, you have to include in `Kernel` and after to `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried

```
Object.send(:include,Foo)
```

or

```
self.send(:include,Foo)
```

inside your console

Comment: Using 'Object.send' worked. Wonder if there is better class to use for this and not use Object, seem too general for this. But it works :) Thank you.